# Separating a text into 3 parts

Tags: c#, sql, string, textbox

i have 3 textbox that determines an Employee's ID the question is how to retrieve the EID from sql and separate a text from sql into 3 strings that will go to their respective textbox here's the format

```
//Column name from database is EID 
txtbox1 = EID1 //YEAR OF EMPLOYMENT = 2017
txtbox2 = EID2 //EMPLOYEE CATEGORY = 01
txtbox3 = EID3 //EMPLOYEE NUMBER = 0001
string EID = EID1+EID2+EID3; //output will be 2017010001
```

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using ?

Comment: If the entry has a fixed format like 4 digit year, 2 digit month and 4 digit employee number you can easily do so with splitting the string based on index. Or do you have delimiters like 2017-01-0001?

Comment: You better pray that the length of those numbers is guaranteed to be constant. If not, you better just start praying in general.

Comment: i'm using xampp sql

Comment: Please read [ask], explain what part specifically you need help with, show the actual code you currently have and share your research. You just need to take substrings of varying length, or so it seems.

Comment: @AshharHasan their constant but we dont have delimiters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve the entire EID from the database

```
var empID = DataRow["EmpID"];
txtbox1.Text = empID.Substring(0,4);
txtbox2.Text = empID.Substring(4,2);
txtbox3.Text = empID.Substring(6, empID.Length-4);
```

Now, there are a bunch of suppositions attached here. This code will only work if the employee ID is as you state, and never, ever changes. I made the assumption that employee number is the remainder of the string. Also there are magic numbers...

There are much better ways to do what you are asking, but we cannot know your direction with such a limited amount of data.

Comment: Yep, I think he needs this.

Comment: Thanks! this helped a lot

Comment: you're welcome, but remember, that code is fragile. I could come up with many things that break it..
you could accept the answer if it suited your needs.

Comment: also note that substring with a single parameter will take the rest of the string, so txtBox3.Text=empID.Substring(6) would start at position 6 and take the rest of the string, regardless of length.

Comment: @CharlesMay - correct. Didn't want to have to explain using different signatures too...